# calculo com dados do BD, trazer serviço, valor e total

Tags: php, banco-de-dados, mysqli

Preciso salvar `cliente, serviço, valor` de um serviço. O primeiro problema é conseguir retornar o valor total (a soma dos serviços).

Meu `form` até o momento está assim:

```
<form action="valortotal.php" method="post">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="autocomplete" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Cliente: </label>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <input id="autocomplete">
        </div>
    </div>
    <br><br>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Serviços: </label>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <?php
            $query_servicos = "SELECT * FROM servicos ORDER BY nome ASC";
            $result_servicos = mysqli_query($conectar, $query_servicos);
            while ($linhas_servicos = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_servicos)) {
                echo " <input type=checkbox name='nomes[]' value=" . $linhas_servicos['preco'] . "> " . $linhas_servicos['nome'] . "<br>";
            }
            ?>
        </div>
    </div>
    <br>

    <input type=submit>
</form>
```

**Conteúdo do valortotal.php:**

```
<?php
// Verifica se usuário escolheu algum número
if (isset($_POST["nomes"])) {
    echo "Os números de sua preferência são:<BR>";

    // Faz loop pelo array dos numeros
    foreach ($_POST["nomes"] as $nomes) {
        echo $nomes + $nomes . "<BR>";
    }
}
```

Ele está somando individualmente. Como faço para pegar a soma total ?

Comment: Ronaldo, seja bem vindo. Sei que a sua pergunta não foi essa, mas tem algo muito errado no seu código. Você não deveria colocar a busca ao banco de dados no meio do seu html. O ideal seria separar essa responsabilidade em outra classe. Isso pode te trazer problemas no futuro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Faltou pouco para chegar na resposta certa... Você deve definir uma variável para fazer a soma dos dados que você quer... Eu faria assim:

```
<?php
// Verifica se usuário escolheu algum número
if (isset($_POST["nomes"])) {
    echo "Os números de sua preferência são:<BR>";

    $totalServicos = 0;
    // Faz loop pelo array dos numeros
    foreach ($_POST["nomes"] as $nomes) {
        $totalServicos += $nomes;
    }

    echo "R$ ".number_format($totalServicos, 2, ',', '.');
}
```